# Apache CXF - Null Pointer Exception in WSDLServiceFactory

Tags: java, apache, cxf

When I execute a jar I receive this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
at it.finanze.dogane.domest.otello.accesspoint.wsdl.Otello_Service.<init>(Otello_Service.java:44)
at it.sknt.truckonesender.App.main(App.java:70)
```

Inside the generated service class I have:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "Otello",
              wsdlLocation = "classpath:Otello.wsdl",
              targetNamespace = "http://accessPoint.otello.domest.dogane.finanze.it/wsdl/")
```

public class Otello_Service extends Service {

```
public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://accessPoint.otello.domest.dogane.finanze.it/wsdl/", "Otello");
public final static QName Otello = new QName("http://accessPoint.otello.domest.dogane.finanze.it/wsdl/", "Otello");
static {
    URL url = Otello_Service.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Otello.wsdl");
    if (url == null) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Otello_Service.class.getName())
            .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO,
                 "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "classpath:Otello.wsdl");
    }
    WSDL_LOCATION = url;
} .....
```

Inside my POM file I have:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>classpath:Otello.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And these are the cxf packages added to project

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Everithing works fine if I execute the program from netbeans.

The wdsl file is under src/main/resources. The wsdl implementation is automatically generated and are place under target/generated-sources/cxf

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add those two tags between `<wsdlOption>` tag:

```
 <wsdl>src/main/resources/Otello.wsdl</wsdl> 
 <wsdlLocation>classpath:Otello.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
```

In `<wsdl>` tag you need provide path relative to project directory.

Comment: I tried but I always have the same error... If help I use the version 3.2.6 of cxf

Comment: Make an update and add your directory structure (with WSDL location), might be helpful.

Comment: The wdsl file is under src/main/resources. The wsdl implementation is automatically generated and are place under target/generated-sources/cxf

Comment: the url that is used inside the service to access the wsdl is the following jar:file:/var/www/html/Clienti/TruckOne/TruckOneSender/target/TruckOneSender-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/Otello.wsdl